# PHP and Twig array iteration

Tags: php, arrays, twig, iteration

Hello I've got a php array $arrayTitle that I have coverted into Twig:

```
echo $twig->render('newline.twig', array(
'allTheTitles' => $arrayTitle ));
```

and I want Twig to iterate the array:

```
{% for i in allTheTitles %}
<option>{{ i.allTheTitles }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

unluckily this is the effect I get:

```
 <select>
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
 </select>
```

so it's as if Twig understood that it's an array and it guessed its lenght (2) but for some incomprehensible for me reason it doesn't return the values of the array. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: should it just be `{{ i }}` perhaps? since `i` is representing the current iteration value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below

```
{% for i in allTheTitles %}
<option>{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

If not works then , share value of `$arrayTitle` ?